# Traversing the DOM indepth

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this TR tag

```
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td><a class="links" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/jannuelanarna">Jannuel Christian Anarna</a></td>
   <td>Calabarzon, Philippines</td>
   <td>Market Research</td>
   <td>BDA Partnership</td>
   <td>Inside Sales Representative</td>
   <td><a href="#">Invite</a></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
</tr>
```

Now I've targeted the a.links with :

```
var memberDiv = document.getElementByClassName('links');
```

Now in my code, i have a loop that evaluates if the href value has a  match on an array. And it will return an array matching the values. Now my **question** is, how could I target the `<td>` with an a href, and remove the anchor tag?.

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer without properly reading the question; could you show the array you're comparing the `href` attribute *to*? Also, in your JavaScript, you should have `getElementsByClassName()` (note the plural, from the added `s`), not the singular form (as you wrote it).

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing, and isn't helped by the fact that you've included only a little code. You're returning an Array of what? Of href values? Of Anchor elements? And what do you mean by *"target the `<td>` with an a href"*? That doesn't make much sense. If you already have the `a` element, you have all you need to remove it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HijvMZHb - This is code i used to retrieve and compare the arrays. You can see there my current problem is in 3rd for in loop. If there are a match found, I need to target the Invite Td, remove the anchor.

Comment: Post your (relevant/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) code *here*, in your question.

Answer (score -1):

After reading, I think I understand. You want to remove the anchors within the TD elements that have been found as a match and convert them to regular text, right?

jQuery code to unwrap the anchors would look like this.

```
$('tr td a[href="matched-link.html"]').contents().unwrap();
```

Here's a fiddle showing a test of what I think your question needs: http://jsfiddle.net/EcKKt/

Edit:

For fun, I also created a pure JS example of the same thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/xhR85/

The gist is this:

```
matches.forEach(function(match, i) {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('tr td a[href="' + match + '"]');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element, ii) {
        element.parentNode.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    });
});
```